# IP Route problem on Cisco Router

Tags: cisco, routing

My question is;I can't connect to network  192.168.1.0 .Where I wrong?
Here is my cisco command.Also, no output from  'show ip route' command.

```
Router#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#no ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.2 
Router(config)#wr

Router#sh ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, I - IGRP, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
   D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
   N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
   E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
   i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
   * - candidate default, U - per-user static route, o - ODR
   P - periodic downloaded static route

 Gateway of last resort is not set

 172.168.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       172.168.1.0 is directly connected, Serial0/1/0
C    192.168.2.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
Router#sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 627 bytes
!
version 12.4
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
! 
hostname Router
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain-lookup
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
ip  address 192.168.2.254 255.255.255.0
duplex auto
speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
! 
interface Serial0/1/0
 ip address 172.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
 ipv6 ospf cost 781
 !
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 !
 ip classless
 ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 172.16.1.1 
 !
 !
 !
 no cdp run
 ! 
 !
 !
 !
 !
 line con 0
 line    vty 0 4
 login
 !
 !
 !
 end
```

Comment: Has the 192.168.1.0 vlan got a route back to 172.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24? 
If you don't have any output from sh ip route none of the interfaces are up, what does sh int show?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the conditions of the problem?  I'm sorry but this question is pretty bad right now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to send the traffic over Serial0/1/0 you will need to double check that you entered the correct IP addresses. Serial0/1/0 has 172.168.1.2 where the route has 172.16.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

You are pointing to an ip address that is not present in you routing table. Of course it will not work. I think this should be like this :
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 Serial 0/1/0

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a typo: You are so used to typing 192.168.x.x that when you go to type 172.16.x.x, you actually typed 172.168.x.x, adding the "8".

Answer (score 0):

Like xciter said, there's no 192.168.1.0 interface on the router. Did you mean to have

- ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 172.16.1.1